# Test Post method of Web Service

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a web service with a post method that will get two parameters, JobNumber and AssociateID, from the query string. It is also looking to get an XML Document as a parameter for the Post method [public HttpResponseMessage Post(XMLDocument NobXML)].

How would I write something to test this Post method?

Comment: <form name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/api/XML/Post?JobNumber=2270157&AssociateID=rd0000" method="post">
        <input id="fileinput" name="fileinput" type="file" />
        <input id="fileinput" name="submit" type="submit" />
    </form>

Comment: You will have to write some code to generate the XML document.  I don't think a form can generate XML.